# Finding Twin rooms

Tags: online-resources, bookings, hotels

I'm checking a lot of sites trying to find twin rooms, on both [Expedia](http://www.expedia.com) and [Agoda](http://www.agoda.com/), and unless I'm looking at hostels there seems to be a considerable lack of twin rooms advertised.

Is this a case that I need to just ring ahead and ask that they prepare my double room as a twin, or is this too presumptuous?

Comment: What is a twin room? And what country are you looking for one in?

Comment: @Kate: a twin room is like a double room, but with 2 separate single beds, instead of one double one.

Comment: I suspect you'll have more luck finding rooms with two double beds. In the USA I find 2 double beds in my room as often as I find one (typically rooms in a conference block booked by the organizers.)

Comment: what country are you looking for hotels in. i used expedia last week to book a room with 2 queen beds in las vegas (i assume this still counts as a twin as i think it would be a little awkward to have 2 couples in there).

Comment: Not all double rooms are convertable to 2 single beds. Best to ring up first.

Comment: Are you looking at hotels or hostels? The post in confusing because you say "hostels" but you're using the tag "hotels" and the answers will vary accordingly. I work at a hostel in Australia and we specifically have both double and twin rooms as well as dormitories. Frequently though we get couples booking a twin or two guys booking a double so I guess the terminology is not known everywhere. I always say as a mnemonic "well twins don't usually sleep together" (-;

Comment: I'm only looking for Hotels, but on websites such as Expedia/Agoda, they don't have any mention of Twin Rooms for Hotels. However the search result is mixed with Hostels, and for Hostels they list Single/Twin/Triple. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I usually use [booking.com](http://www.booking.com) for my hotel searches, and they've previously let me select twin rooms, if that helps at all.  I suspect it's largely dependent on the search tool itself.

Comment: Wow booking.com really does seem to offer more info about twin rooms. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Terms vary country to country, so it's always a good idea to make sure you confirm that what you're getting is what you're after.

In the US a "twin" bed refers to a the same thing that a "Single" bed refers to in most of the rest of the world.  ie, one bed, suitable for sleeping one person.  If you're after a room with 2 beds it would normally be stated as explicitly having 2 beds - something like "2 twin" or "2 Queens".

For non-US, "twin" in a hotel/motel would normally refer to 2 beds, which could be two single beds, or two larger beds (double, aka "full" in the US, or queen).  eg, you might find a "Twin Queen", a "Twin Single", or even a "Twin Queen/Single" which would have one or each.

Answer (score 5):

Many hotels don't follow the classification. I usually call and look at pictures to make sure I know the room type I want at check-in. Some hotels allow cancellation before 6 PM at the day of check-in - so you can show up - check the rooms and still cancel if you do not like it...

Answer (score -3):

I can't recall ever seeing a twin bed in a US hotel room.  They're always at least doubles, what you would be after is a room with two doubles.

I have seen twin beds in third world locations, though.

Comment: I'm sleeping in a twin bed tonight, in a nice hotel in Sweden. They are certainly more common in Europe, where space is more at a premium.

Comment: Methinks you misunderstand the [terminology](http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/5691/253) of the questioner. To me, the phrase "a twin bed" seems rather odd: it needs something to be twinned *with*. They come in pairs.

Comment: Stayed in one in Vegas.....and SF....among others.  LA too.